# MySQL - AFTER UPDATE Trigger between Two Databases

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, schema

Been having some issues with this for a few hours.  I'm by no means a MySQL guy and have been looking for a solution but no luck.  Here's essentially what I have..

T1: `CollectionDB`.source

```
indexName | status_id
   Test   |     11
```

T2:  `ManagementConsole`.MC_SCHEDULE

```
NAME      | ACTIVE
Test      |    0
```

Basically, the trigger I need should run after T1.status_id has changed from any number to 8.  When it runs, it should find T2.NAME that matches the corresponding T1.indexName and change ACTIVE from 0 to 1.  Here's what I have thus far.

```
DELIMITER &&

CREATE TRIGGER `UpdateSynch`
AFTER UPDATE ON `CollectionDB`.source FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

UPDATE `ManagementConsole`.MC_SCHEDULE AS T1
SET T1.ACTIVE = 1
WHERE (NOW.indexName = T1.NAME) AND ((OLD.status_id != 8) AND (NOW.status_id = 8));

END&&
```

I'm getting a 'Trigger in wrong schema' error, which makes sense since I'm trying to make an update in a different schema.  Is there any way around this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create the trigger in the same database as the target table, i.e. `CollectionDB`; however, you must currently have another database selected as your default schema.

Therefore, either:

1. Change your default schema to the `CollectionDB` database before attempting to create the trigger:

   ```
   USE CollectionDB;
   CREATE TRIGGER UpdateSynch ...
   ```
2. Explicitly specify in the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement the database in which you want it to be created:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER CollectionDB.UpdateSynch ...
   ```